# View Pager EditText hint issue in Landscape mode

Tags: android-edittext, android-viewpager, landscape, hint, android-textinputedittext

Using View Pager I want to change edit text hint runtime, It displays correct hint when I scroll view pager but when I tape on edit text to write something it shows wrong hint(Hint of the previous page), you can check with gif file that I have attached.

> Note: When I set Text on edit text this issue is not found, it occurs only with a set hint. I'm using `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`. The app is in Landscape mode. It is working fine in portrait mode.

[image]

[image]

Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Hey buddy, I am facing similar issue. This occurs only in landscape mode.